# diacritics in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, diacritics

my question is maybe a dumb one, but i cant help myself - i created a flash movie with a dynamicly inserted textfield, that loads its text from a file, but i have problems viewing diacritics like ľščťžýáíé in it. I tried to change font, but it didnt help. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Any of the standard fonts (Times New Roman, Arial) will properly display your example string in a Flash Pro dynamic text field. Have you tried them? How are you reading in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you must make sure that the font is embedded properly, this can be tested easily by just typing those very characters into the textfield, and if they show up on export you're good to go.

As for reading the textfile things are slightly more complex, but not by much. What you need to do is to make sure that the textfile you are reading is in UTF8, any reasonable text editor should be able to save this (hell, even notepad does it now). 
You can make flash respect your local character encoding, but that is very error prone and will likely break if someone with a different encoding views your app. So go for UTF8, flash handles that with ease.

Comment: i deal with this nearly every day as most of the web development i do is in swedish. so i've had nearly every charset issue there is with flash :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use those you'll need to embed them into you application. The easiest way is to create a new TextField on your stage, then under the properties panel, embed those characters (You'll need to embed them for the specific font you are using). Just create your TextField out of view, and you sould be good to go.